# what are all the required steps to convert a NetLogo GUI model to run headless mode on a cluster?

Tags: netlogo, headless

Other than avoiding clear-all in headless mode, do we need to convert "all" the switches and sliders to global variables? what else should be done to run a large NetLogo model on a cluster without GUI?

I have followed this https://www.openmole.org/Netlogo+Headless.html guide to convert my model but I don't know how we set the values if we remove the init-globals in the headless setup? I get the div/0 error due to not initializing the explicit global variable by following the exact steps, after that, I added the explicit global variable to behavior space with 2 values but I have got the exact same results for both experiments which is not correct.

Behavior space is useful for creating experiments easily when a model has lots of sliders and switches because it pre-populates the new experiment parameters and we only need to add the required values for each parameter (true-false or numerical values). However, when all the switches are converted to explicit global variable how can we use behavior space? does it work the same way as implicit GUI widgets? can we have explicit global variables in behavior space, I have tested my model for this and I got an exact same result for all of the experiments runs, what should I look for to resolve the issue?

Comment: Are you actually using OpenMOLE? If not, you should not be following that guide. That guide is sort of opposite of what you want to do for just running behaviorspace headlessly.

Comment: Hi @Bryan, Thank you very much, No I am not using OpenMole. Good to know because it was confusing and I couldn't get it work, however, I count find a good step by step guide to make my complex model to work on headless mode.

Comment: I have read in another answer that sliders are useless in headless mode, but if they are useless then what should be included in the behaviour space experiments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in a comment, those directions are for OpenMOLE specifically, and are practically the opposite of what you want to do for just running headless BehaviorSpace.

For a headless model, you should actually leave all those switches and sliders as switches and sliders. Input widgets just create globals that aren't cleared by `clear-all`: they function just fine in headless mode. Sure, they can't be used, but they still provide a way of setting things that aren't cleared in `setup`, which is exactly what you want. NetLogo was designed to run normal GUI models seamlessly as headless BehaviorSpace experiments. Indeed, even if you run BehaviorSpace in the GUI, it runs headless versions of the model in the background to take advantage of multi-core processors.

Thus, the way to turn a GUI model in a headless model is to not change a thing! *All* of the parameters you want to vary in an experiment should be implemented as input widgets. `setup` absolutely should call `clear-all`. This is the easiest way to guarantee clean experiments and that multiple runs aren't bleeding into each other.

That said, make sure you are designing your model setup and so forth so that the model is setup completely from setting input widgets (sliders, switches, etc) and running `setup`. It should not require any further interaction with the user (such as, using the mouse to move things around).

There are *some* exceptions to this advice. If your model requires loading large file, or has a particularly expensive `setup` that doesn't actually need to be rerun between simulations, you have to tweak things. However, these are special cases and if you're dealing with them, should be addressed in a separate answer.

Comment: Thank you, that's great, as you mentioned I won't have to interact with the model even when it is running with GUI, so I think the model in its initial state was already ready to run in headless mode. Thank you for your response :). The setup just creates different settings for each run, therefore, its not one of the special cases.